# Mandatory keywords arguments

Tags: python

Some functions in Python standard library have (optional) keyword argument(s), but using them in the form of keyword arguments is *optional* , e. g.

```
enumerate(iterable, start=1)    # as keyword argument
```

and

```
enumerate(iterabele, 1)         # as positional argument
```

are *both correct*.

But others *explicitly forbid* using their optional keyword arguments as positional, e. g. `sorted()`:

> ```
> sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)
>    Return a new sorted list from the items in iterable.
>    Has two optional arguments which must be specified as keyword arguments.
> ```

(See also [PEP 3102 - Keyword-Only Arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).)

Why such decision for only few keyword arguments? What would be bad with such (incorrect) use:

```
sorted(strings_list, len, True)        # Incorrect, but why not allowed?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can only speculate, of course. `sorted` used to have a different type of arguments in python 2.x. So, it is very likely that the python 3.x version *forces you* to use keyword arguments for the new arguments to avoid, accidentally, passing python 2 code that does something entirely different in python 3, without giving you any warning.

On the other hand, this is the exception, not the rule. The `enumerate` example you give has nothing special, it follows the standard python rules.

Answer (score 2):

With positional arguments you have to pass them in the order they're defined... (let's assume key then reversed here...). If that was allowed then to sort with no key, but in reverse order you'd have to write: `sorted(iterable, None, True)`... and if you forgot the ordering of the arguments and thought the first argument was the ordering then `sorted(iterable, True)` would break.

Now, you could argue that you could avoid the explicit `None` by writing: `sorted(iterable, reversed=True)`... in which case, you might as well force keyword only arguments to make sure mishaps don't happen which is the design choice taken for `.sort` and `sorted`...

If there's no logical ordering to the arguments - for instance - does it make more sense for `sorted` to take `key` as the first argument or the `reversed` argument. One could argue that sorting something without a key is most likely the common use case - so `reversed` should be the first argument... You could also argue that since ascending is by far the most commonly wanted sort order then `key` should be the first argument.

With `enumerate` for instance - there's no confusion over what the `1` means in `enumerate(iterable, 1)` - it's always the start argument... you can provide it explicitly with a name or not...

If in doubt - make the function signature such that it's explicit as to each argument and avoid ambiguities that can occur from optional positional arguments.